# Dash Radial Plot for Hours of a Day

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am looking for a plot in Ploty/Dash which is similar to radial chart below. The closest one I found in Ploty is polar charts, and line charts.

[image]

Here is my implementation:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME':pd.date_range('2022-11-01', '2022-11-05 23:00:00',freq='h'),
                   'value':[random.uniform(110, 160) for n in range(120)]})

fig = px.line_polar(df, r='DATE_TIME', theta='value', line_close=True)
fig.show()
```

and the my output looks like:

[image]

Instead of angles, I would like to plot hours like 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, and so on.
Besides, my line is not in circle shape. I would appreciate any hints, or solutions.

Comment: Your points are scattered and line are connected these points, therefore you got this shape.

Comment: Also, it is not clear to me what you want to plot on the radial axis(r) and on the angle axis (theta)

Comment: @Hamzah I would like to plot value column on radial axis. On theta, I would like to show hours.

Comment: @Hamzah Should I change to a different shape?

Comment: I added version 2 to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert your hourly data to string series as follows:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME':pd.date_range('2022-11-01', '2022-11-05 23:00:00',freq="30min"),
                   'value':[random.uniform(110, 160) for n in range(239)]})
```

You can plot it this way:

```
fig = px.line_polar(df, r='value', theta=df['DATE_TIME'].dt.strftime('%H:%M'))
fig.update_layout(width=750, height=750)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to show the points scattered like minutes? Because values of 12 and 12:30 are on the same line

Comment: There are no minutes in the data you provided :)

Comment: @dspractician , how do you want to add minutes and your theta is hours?

Comment: I will think of a way for that and open a new question. Meanwhile can you check this question? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74448717/dash-choosing-an-id-and-then-make-plot-with-multiple-sliders

Comment: @dspractician Let me update the answer based on 30 minutes.

Comment: Can I ask why you are using `date_time` as both radius and angle while you use `value` as color? The original question seems to ask -based on the example image- `date_time` as an angle, `value` as the radius and static coloring.

Comment: @dspractician Because in the comments of your question, you asked  the angle to be hours which included in `date_time` and the radius is the date which is also included in `date_time`. The only place you can use `value` is the color attribute.

Comment: That is  indeed what I wanted really thanks! @Hamzah